# notifyDataSetChanged() not refreshing onStart or onPause

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, activity-lifecycle, notifydatasetchanged

I have an issue where I'm in activity A with a recyclerview that shows a list of connected devices. There is 1 connected device which is displayed.

I go to activity B which is now in the foreground and activity A is in the background. I connect a device in activity B.

I get back to activity A which should show 2 devices. However, it shows 1 device, then the screen re-flashes and shows two devices.

I would want it to show two devices as soon as the activity resumes. I've tried clearing the list and calling notifyDataSetChanged onPause and onStart so the recyclerview will be empty when the activity resumes. Then the livedata will be triggered to show the most recent state of connected device. However, it doesn't refresh the UI before the activity is paused or started. It saves the old UI and will then refresh when the activity resumes.

```
private lateinit var viewModel: ViewModel
private lateinit var adapter: Adapter
private var deviceItems = ArrayList<Item>()


override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_v2ps, container, false)
        viewModel = getViewModel()
        return rootView
    }

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        adapter = adapter(deviceItems))
        recycler_view.adapter = adapter
        subscribeToChanges()
    }

private fun subscribeToChanges() {
        viewModel.deviceList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { deviceList ->
            deviceItems.clear()
            deviceItems.addAll(deviceList.map {
                deviceItemMapper.apply(it)
            })
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
        })
    }
```

Tried solution.

```
override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    deviceItems.clear()
    v2psAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```

Comment: you say you have activities but you are showing fragment code

Comment: Every activity has a corresponding fragment where all the logic is located.